# error routing to Register method, Web API 2

Tags: c#, jquery, api, asp.net-web-api

I have a simple form which uses Jquery to post to /api/account/register within a Web API2 project.

The form is really simple:

```
  <body>
    <form id="userData">
        <input type="text" id="userName" placeholder="Name"/>
        <br />
        <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password"/>
        <br />
        <input type="password" id="ConfirmPassword" placeholder="Password" />
        <br />
        <input type="button"  id="register" value="register" />

    </form>
    <pre id="output"></pre>

    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var showResponse = function (object) {
            $("#output").text(JSON.stringify(object, null, 4));
        };

        var register = function() {

            var url = "/api/account/register";
            var data = $("#userData").serialize();
            $.post(url, data).always(showResponse);
            return false;
        };

        $("#register").click(register);
    </script>
</body>
```

however, when I click the register button i'm being presented with:

```
{
"readyState": 4,
"responseText": "{\"Message\":\"An error has occurred.\",\"ExceptionMessage\":\"Object reference not set to an instance of an object.\",\"ExceptionType\":\"System.NullReferenceException\",\"StackTrace\":\"   at System.Web.Http.ApiController.<InvokeActionWithExceptionFilters>d__1.MoveNext()\\r\\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\\r\\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\\r\\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\\r\\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\\r\\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__0.MoveNext()\"}",
"responseJSON": {
    "Message": "An error has occurred.",
    "ExceptionMessage": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.",
    "ExceptionType": "System.NullReferenceException",
    "StackTrace": "   at System.Web.Http.ApiController.<InvokeActionWithExceptionFilters>d__1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__0.MoveNext()"
},
"status": 500,
"statusText": "Internal Server Error"
```

}

Comment: Can you show us your controller code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is problem to serialize the form.
To do it correctly you need to add the name to each element:

```
<form id="userData">
    <input type="text" id="userName" name="userName" placeholder="Name" />
    <br />
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
    <br />
    <input type="password" id="ConfirmPassword" name="ConfirmPassword" placeholder="Password" />
    <br />
    <input type="button" id="register" name="register" value="register" />
</form>
```

This is independent of jQuery. Every form element must have a name to be considered for form submission as successful control

Comment: typo /api/account/register.

Comment: ok, not sure when the local db gets created, but my Webconfig file is pointing to a mdf which doesn't exists. this must be the reason for the error.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, sorted this by renaming the default database name in the config to something else, and then sent a post to api/account/register and it created the database.